# C++: Syntax error: 'string' but still compiler successfuly in another project?

Tags: c++, string, notifications, syntax-error

I have coppied one code file into my code from another code where it was compiled successfully, but in my code, it has many error, same like others. Like this:

```
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\pathcch.h(34): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'

1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\pathcch.h(34): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body

1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkey.h(37): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'

1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkey.h(37): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkey.h(49): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'

1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkey.h(49): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkey.h(57): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'

1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkey.h(57): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkey.h(65): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'

1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkey.h(65): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

please help me, thanks!

SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH.

Comment: Are you trying to compile a driver ?

Comment: @Nina: sorry, i dont know how to compile driver, can you tell me? thanks.

Comment: Are you certain you are compiling C++ and not C?

Comment: BTW, if you need any information to clarify the problem, please tell me, i will show it up.

Comment: @user4581301 yes, I compile with C++, use visual 2019, use "platform toolset" : "VS2017 (v141)"

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @Nina here is my code: https://pastebin.com/1DqRyBf9

Comment: @AnhHuânLê please [edit] your question to show your code HERE on StackOverflow, not on another site

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry about that, my code is too long to show HERE

Comment: Please, read about [mcve]. You should reduce your code until you get a minimal amount with same errors. As certain errors seem to repeat, it might be sufficient for beginning to reproduce only the first error.

Comment: Add '#include <string>' and 'using namespace std;' at the top of your file for testing

Comment: @Scheff : Those error are in the default library. I dont think I should change them, sir.

Comment: I doubt that the errors are in the default library. Please, consider that an `#include` works like copy/pasting the included file where the `#include` appears. So, the error message might come from a valid code compiled at a wrong place (or with a wrong compiler, or with wrong settings). (But, I agree. I wouldn't hardly change headers as well which are not mine.) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have that version of Windows SDK installed.

pathcch.h line 34 says

```
extern "C" {
```

propkey.h contains code like this in the lines which fail:

```
DEFINE_PROPERTYKEY(PKEY_Audio_ChannelCount, 0x64440490, 0x4C8B, 0x11D1, 0x8B, 0x70, 0x08, 0x00, 0x36, 0xB1, 0x1A, 0x03, 7);
```

`DEFINE_PROPERTYKEY` macro is defined in propkeydef.h, and it expands into

```
EXTERN_C const PROPERTYKEY DECLSPEC_SELECTANY name = ...
```

The reason for that compiler error is `extern "C"`

One possible reason, you’re compiling your source code with C compiler instead of C++ compiler.

There’s no `extern "C"` in C language, it’s only in C++.

If you’re using Visual C++, by default, it detects language from file extension. Easy way to fix, rename your source file extension to `*.cpp` or `*.cxx`.

[Here’s more info.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type?view=vs-2019#remarks)

Another possible reason, you’re using non-Microsoft’s compiler. If that’s the case, please specify compiler + version in the question, probably someone will answer.

**Update:** I recommend creating a new project of the correct type (probably C++ / windows desktop / Windows Desktop Application), ensure it compiles and run, then start adding your code. Do it gradually.
First remove everything from the main .cpp file, only leave `#include "stdafx.h"` and 
`wWinMain` function, just return 0 from that function. Then add your `#include` statements, they should go to stdafx.h. Then add `#pragma comment` section, they should go to some .cpp file, doesn’t matter which one. Finally, add your code to the main .cpp file. Between every step, ensure the project builds.

Comment: thanks for your help, I also chang file (from `".h"` to `".cpp"`) and error change to `'#include' statement specified with the /Ycstdafx.h command-line option was not found in the source file` at stdafx.cpp, it define `"include: precomp.h"`, I'm trying to fix it :D

Comment: @AnhHuânLê The error is not in the code you’re using, it’s in your project setup. I think you should learn C++, 2 things in particular (1) what’s the difference between header file and source file (2, Microsoft specific) what’s precompiled header and how to set up and use them.

Comment: Yup, I'm newbie in OOP C++, i'll research it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AnhHuânLê Well, everyone starts somewhere. See also the update.

Comment: I'm doing what you told, but I dont know how to add `#pragma comment`, can I use `#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")` ? looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Comment: @AnhHuânLê Copy-paste the complete `#if` .. `#endif` portion of your source into some .cpp file in your project. The main .cpp will do, or you can create another one, `manifest.cpp`

Comment: I did, and it working correctly

Comment: now, im trying to merge it to my source code, ty

Answer (score 0):

Try to add '#include “string“' to the includes and add 'using namespace std;'   with that you can make sure if it is a missing include/namespace using.

Comment: Windows SDK doesn’t use STL, the OP's error is unrelated to `std::string`

Comment: I also think it is unrelated to `std::string`

Comment: Does the windows SDK define it's own string type?